# How to query MySQL by one of the field's subvalue?

Tags: mysql

**Let's assume there is a table, with theese rows:**

```
-personID,
-personName,
-personInterests
```

**There is also another table, which stores the interests:**

```
-interestID
-interestName
```

One person can have multiple interests, so I put the `serialize()`-d or `JSON` representation of the `interest array` into the `interest` field. This is not a `String`, like "reading", buth rather an index of the `interests` table, which stores the possible interests. Something like multiple foreign keys in one field.

The best way would be to use foreign keys, but it is not possible to achieve multiple references in one field...

How do I run such a query, **without** `REGEX` or splitting the field's content by software? If putting indexes to one field is not the way to go, then how is it possible, to achieve a structure like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing multiple indexes or any references in one field is strictly not advised.
You have to create something that I call "rendezvous" table.

In your case it has:

```
 - ID
 - UserID (foreign key)
 - InterestID (foreign key)
```

Every single person can have multiple interests, so when a person adds a new interest to himself, you just add a new row into this table, that will have a reference to the person and the desired interest with a foreign key `NOT NULL`.

On large-scale projects when there are too many variations available, it is advised, to not to give an `ID` row to this table, but rather set the two `foreign keys` also `primary keys`, so the duplication will be impossible and the `table-index` will be smaller, as well as in case of lookup, it will consume less from the expensive computing power.

So the best solution is this:

```
 - UserID (foreign key AND primary key)
 - InterestID (foreign key AND primary key)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way you can implement this is to create a third table, which will actually get updated by a trigger (Similar to what Gabor Dani advised)

```
Table1 
-personID,
-personName,
-personInterests

Table2 
-interestID
-interestName

Table3 
-personInterestID (AutoIncrement Field)
-personID
-interestID
```

Then you need to write a trigger which will do this a stored procedure may be needed because you will need to loop through all the values in the field.